# How to use code in an editor block?

Tags: shortcode, block-editor

I am trying to execute code in a block such that I can display the title and description of a forum topic.

I noticed that the Custom HTML block doesn't seem to allow me to execute PHP.

What is the standard way to do what I am trying to do? Maybe I have to create a custom shortcode?

thanks,
Brian

Comment: Yes a shortcode would work, but the ‘standard’ way would be to create a block for it.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to create a Shortcode in the functions.php file of your theme and then use it in Gutenberg.

Gutenberg has a built-in block to add shortcodes.

Basically, you will add the following code to your functions.php file,

```
function get_forum_post_information( $atts ) {
    // The PHP Code that you want to execute to get the Title and Description.
    return your_stuff;
}
add_shortcode( "get_forum_post_information", "get_forum_post_information" );
```

Once you are done creating your shortcode, you can simply go to Gutenberg, click the + button to add a new Block, search for Shortcode, then select it.

Gutenberg will put in a block that can be used to run that shortcode. Then simply enter the shortcode in that block as below,

```
[get_forum_post_information]
```

Note: You can also pass function parameters through the shortcode if you would like and then access them through the $atts array in the function. A shortcode always returns something to be echoed.

Read more about [Shortcodes on the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

Read about the [Gutenberg Shortcode Block](https://gogutenberg.com/blocks/shortcode/)

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I am doing something similar with a hook and ran into the problem os not quite knowing the wordpress way to access a plugin's classes/models. Is that plugin specific or is there a general way to go about it. So if some plugin has a post type called topic, is there a core way to load its model?

Comment: @Brian The WordPress way of registering a custom post type is by using register_post_type function, so if you want to access posts from a post type registered by a plugin, you can do it through [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) by passing the "post_type" => "your post type" as an argument.